# Android parse json array between json object

Tags: android, json

I tried to parse this json array and  json objects but give me error and not recieve any data, can you help me to parse this;

Here my json link:

http://almahdishop.com/api/posts.json?fields=id,title,thumb&limit=10

Here My Code:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsStr);

                for (int i = 0; i <jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jso = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("id_product", jso.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jso.getString("title"));
                    map.put("model","");
                    map.put("price", "14000");
                    map.put("oldprice", "14000");
                    map.put("logo", jso.getString("thumb"));

                     arraylist.add(map);
                 }
```

Comment: Paste your error message by editing your post please.

Comment: No data recieve and error is my custom error

Comment: this is complete valid json ..what errors you got? may be issue with manipulations

Comment: I updated my question plz read again

Comment: is your jsonarray get all response which you have? because you must to get first whole object and after that items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like this

```
try {

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray itemsArray = data.getJSONArray("items");

         for (int i = 0; i <itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jso = itemsArray .getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("id_product", jso.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jso.getString("title"));
                    map.put("model","");
                    map.put("price", "14000");
                    map.put("oldprice", "14000");
                    map.put("logo", jso.getString("thumb"));
                     arraylist.add(map);
                 }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse this json as follows :

```
 try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem comes from parsing.
Please use org.JSON.simple.-111.jar.